# Reclassifying RasterStack by function and overlaying in R

Tags: raster, r

I've got a RasterStack composed of a four rasters. See below:

```
# Reproducible examples
kiwi <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -56, ymx = 84, res = 1)
kiwi[] <- sample(2:35, ncell(kiwi), replace = T)

banana <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 179.9999, ymn = -56.00081, ymx = 83.99917, 
res = 1)
banana[] <- sample(2:100, ncell(banana), replace = T)

apple <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -56, ymx = 84, res = 1)
apple[] <- sample(4:100, ncell(apple), replace = T)

mango <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -56, ymx = 84, res = 1)
mango[] <- sample(1:90, ncell(mango), replace = T)

# Raster stack
stacked<-stack(kiwi, banana, apple, mango)
```

I want to reclassify the RasterStack into four categories (`tropical`, `mediterranean`, `boreal` and `savannah`) based on some conditions (see below), and then combine into one raster and plot all four categories on a single map.

```
# Example conditions 
 kiwi < 10 & banana > 20 & mango > 0.5 == "tropical" 
 mango > 15 & apple < 10 == "boreal"
```

I think I need to create a `function` and apply it to `overlay` but I don't know how to write this function. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer `raster::calc` for this type of function. This is because you can pass it a raster stack or brick and index the vector based on the layers in the stack. With `raster::overlay` you use x and y arguments, which makes the problem at hand overly complicated.

Let's replicate your example but, note that I am toning down the dimensions a bit (no need to run a n=50,400 example when n=504 will do). Also note that you cannot use character output (eg., tropical, boreal) for a raster, it must be numerically encoded (eg., tropical=1, boreal=2).

```
library(raster)

kiwi <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -56, ymx = 84, res = 10)
  kiwi[] <- sample(2:35, ncell(kiwi), replace = TRUE)
banana <- kiwi
  banana[] <- sample(2:100, ncell(banana), replace = TRUE)
apple <- kiwi
  apple[] <- sample(4:100, ncell(apple), replace = TRUE)
mango <- kiwi
  mango[] <- sample(1:90, ncell(mango), replace = TRUE)
```

Here we create a raster stack object.

```
fruit <- stack(kiwi, banana, apple, mango)
```

Now, we write a function that simply indexes the band in the stack (eg., kiwi = 1, banana = 2, apple = 3, mango = 4). Now you can just think of it in terms of which position in a vector do you need to index  (eg., for `x=c(6,81,20,26),` `x[1]` would be kiwi and a value of 6). With a function in hand, using a nested `ifelse` function to reclassify the data, we can pass it to `raster::calc`.

```
system.class <- function(x, rm.na, ...) {
  return( ifelse(x[1] < 10 & x[2] > 20 & x[4] < 15, 1,
            ifelse(x[4] > 15 & x[3] < 10, 2, 0)) )
}

( fruit.class <- calc(fruit, system.class) )
  plot(fruit.class)
```

You can visualize what is happening here a bit better by coercing to an sp object. The @data slot is a dataframe containing the raster data by row. That is to say that each row in the dataframe represents a single pixel across all the layers. Using this format we can use the apply function to pass our function to the data. The result will be a vector of the results. This would represent a single band raster.

```
f <- as(fruit, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  head(f@data)

( f.class <- apply(f@data, MARGIN=1, FUN=system.class) ) 
  f@data$class <- f.class 

plot(raster(f,layer=5))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in-depth explanation. It works great